# How to include PHP in template?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to use [WP Ultimate Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ultimate-search/installation/)  and it says:

> Call the search bar with wp_ultimate_search_bar() Render the search
>   results area with wp_ultimate_search_results()

I tried `<?php wp_ultimate_search_bar(); ?>` with no luck.. any ideas?

Comment: `<?php echo wp_ultimate_search_bar(); ?>` maybe?

Comment: How are you trying to use it? Do you want to render it? Because then it looks like you should use `wp_ultimate_search_results()` instead.

Comment: thanks! I had to include both to get the bar and the results to show up.  I would mark 1 as an answer but i cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both `<?php echo wp_ultimate_search_bar(); ?>` and `<?php echo wp_ultimate_search_results(); ?>` to .php file